# How to determine if a package (gulp-copy) goes well with another one (gulp)?

Tags: npm, gulp

I see [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-copy) called *gulp-copy* and I can't see anywhere if it's adopted for the latest version of *gulp*. Is that never an issue? I'm worried that I happen to pick wrong package constellation or perhaps an obsolete configuration all together.

Questions are:

1. In this particular case, does the linked *gulp-copy* work well with *gulp 4*?
2. Is there a general way to determine which packages work well with *gulp*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generalized way to determine whether a certain package only works with gulp 3 or gulp 4 (besides reading the documentation for that package). Package creators cannot programmatically specify what version of gulp their package supports and there's no warning when using a package that's designed for a different version of gulp.

That being said, there are some heuristics you can use depending on what kind of packages you are dealing with:

**General node packages**: those are packages that were not specifically designed for gulp at all. You can use them with gulp, because you can use any node package with gulp, but they make sense outside of gulp as well.

These packages should work with any version of gulp since they don't contain gulp-specific code and are therefore independent of any changes made to gulp. Examples that are often used with gulp are [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) and [`del`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del).

**Gulp-specific packages** on the other hand can be affected by changes to gulp.

Among those there's **gulp plugins** which are packages that are supposed to be used in gulp streams with `.pipe()`. Their names almost always start with `gulp-`, they are tagged with [gulpplugin](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/gulpplugin) on npm and listed on the [GulpJS website](http://gulpjs.com/plugins/).

These should also generally be safe to use with any version of gulp. Gulp streams are just regular nodejs streams, so those plugins should work with either version of gulp (although nodejs streams have their [own history of compatibility problems](https://r.va.gg/2014/06/why-i-dont-use-nodes-core-stream-module.html), but that's not really relevant anymore). Barring major changes to the [`vinyl` file format](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl) there's not much that can happen that might affect gulp plugins.

The `gulp-copy` plugin that you mention falls into this category and should be safe to use with both gulp 3 and gulp 4.

All that being said there are a few gulp plugins that only make sense for a specific version. [`gulp-plumber`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) for example fixes an annoying issue with error handling in streams that is only necessary for gulp 3, but not gulp 4. [`gulp-src-ordered-globs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-src-ordered-globs) circumvents a problem with ignore patterns in gulp 3 that's fixed in gulp 4.

Finally there's what I like to call **gulp extensions**. They're not supposed to be used with `.pipe()`. Instead they extend the capabilities of gulp in other ways.

These are the ones you need to watch out for. A lot of them deal with gulp's task running capabilities which have undergone major changes between gulp 3 and gulp 4. There's probably many packages in this category that only work with a certain version of gulp.

I wouldn't worry too much about it though. Most of those packages will prominently display their limitations in their documentation. [`run-sequence`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) for example has a big fat note at the top informing the user that this is a temporary solution for gulp 3. I published a package named [`gulp-parameterized`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-parameterized) the other day that only works with gulp 4 and it screams so in all-caps at the top of the docs.

Basically scan the documentation of any package you want to use for these kinds of notes and you should be relatively safe.

Comment: Awesome answer. I got cautious when I saw that I needed a package for such a common task as file copying and was afraid that it's obsolete or not needed anymore. I haven't found any examples of how to copy files with Gulp 4 without other packages added, which seemed unexpected.

Comment: You don't need `gulp-copy` to copy files, only `gulp.dest()` (see this [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842771/copying-files-with-gulp)). `gulp-copy` even says so on it's [GitHub page](https://github.com/klaascuvelier/gulp-copy). Honestly I don't think this plugin needs to exist at all. I've certainly never used it myself to copy files and I wouldn't recommended it if asked.

Comment: Good point. Hence my confusion. I though it was used for getting e.g. from *node_modules/some/dist/x.min.css* to *wwwroot/css/x.min.css*, i.e. flattening the structure.