# Copy build files to another project using webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I have two project folders in the same parent folder. One is for front end files (JS, CSS, images etc.) and another is for the backend files. The frontend project uses webpack to build files into a dist folder. The backend project is the one which gets deployed to the server (or run on localhost).

So everytime I make change to a JS or CSS file, I run webpack build, copy the build files from `frontend-project/dist` folder to `backend/frontend/js` or `backend/frontend/css` folder and rerun the backend project.

This is really counter-productive. I want to copy the dist files automatically after build to the `backend-project`. Is there any way to do it in webpack using a plugin or without using one? I have used gulp for such kind of tasks before, but want to rely solely on webpack for now.

I tried the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin), but it doesn't run after the build, thus is not useful for me.

Comment: Please try Gulp.You can refer following url [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842771/copying-files-with-gulp)

Comment: @NishaSalim I don't want to add another dependency on gulp. I am pretty sure there must be a way to do it just using webpack (No custom scripting)

Comment: @noob did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 8):

I see several ways how to reach your purposes:

1. You could specify your `backend/frontend/js` folder as an output folder for your bundles.

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../backend/frontend')
    }
};
```

2. If you need two copies of your bundles (one in frontend folder and another in the backend), you can use [`FileManagerPlugin`](https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin) to copy your bundle files to the backend after finishing of the build.

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    plugins: [
        new FileManagerPlugin({
            events: {
                onEnd: {
                    copy: [
                        {
                            source: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                            destination: path.join(__dirname, '../backend/frontend')
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

3. If you run build manually after every code change, I think this is unproductive. You can use [`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) to run build automatically when you develop. It doesn't store bundles in the file system, it keeps them in memory.

Comment: This was very helpful for me, however there is an error with the code snippet - `onEnd` needs to be wrapped in `events` object. Example usage: https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin#usage